# "ValueError: Unrecognized marker style -d" when looping over markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

I'm trying to code `pyplot` plot that allows different marker styles. The plots are generated in a loop. The markers are picked from a list.
For demonstration purposes I also included a colour list.
The versions are `Python 2.7.9`, `IPython 3.0.0`, `matplotlib 1.4.3.`

Here's a simple code example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,10)
y=x**2

markers=['d','-d','-']
colors=['red', 'green', 'blue']

for i in range(len(markers)):
    plt.plot(x, y, marker=markers[i], color=colors[i])
    plt.show()
```

This manages to produce only the plot for marker='d', for the marker `'-d'` it returns the error:

```
...
C:\Users\batman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.pyc in set_marker(self, marker)
    245                 self._marker_function = self._set_vertices
    246             except ValueError:
--> 247                 raise ValueError('Unrecognized marker style {}'.format(marker))
    248 
    249         self._marker = marker

ValueError: Unrecognized marker style -d
```

*But*, I can get it to work by writing `plt.plot(x, y, markers[i], color=colors[i])` instead.
The `color=...` in comparison works.

I assume it has something to do with the the special characters.
I tried other markers:
The markers `.`,`*` work.
The markers `:`,`--` don't.

I tried prefixing the marker string with `r` or `u` (with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`). Didn't help.

Do I have to escape the marker strings or what's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`markers` describe the points that are plotted with `plt.plot`. So, you can have, for example, `'o', 's', 'D', '^', 'v' '*', '.', ','`, etc. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for a full list of available options.

`'-', '--', ':', '-.'` are not markers, but linestyles.

So, it depends what you are trying to plot. If you want one `Axes` object with diamond markers, another with diamond markers and a line, and a final one with just a line, you could do:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,10)
y=x**2

markers=['d','d','None']
lines=['None','-','-']
colors=['red', 'green', 'blue']

for i in range(len(markers)):
    # I've offset the second and third lines so you can see the differences
    plt.plot(x, y + i*10, marker=markers[i], linestyle=lines[i], color=colors[i])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I indeed missed the difference between `linestyle` and `marker` for `pyplot.plot()` in the documentation. It looks like I got confused from being used to using the `fmt` (keyword-) argument either from `pyplot.errorbar(...,fmt='-d')` (where it has the identifier `fmt`) or `pyplot.plot(...,'-d')` (where it doesn't have that identifier). Add to that that while the doc entry for errorbar contains its call signature, the latter doesn't and mentions `fmt` only in the text. Enough for me to miss it. Now I know. :)